# opencv2/core/eigen.hpp Eigen: does not name a type

Tags: c++, opencv, eigen3

I want to convert Eigen's matrix to opencv's mat. so, I used opencv function 'eigen2cv' included in 'opencv2/core/eigen.hpp'. But,this file seems to not include 'Eigen/Core', so that I got a lot of errors. it told me that 'Eigen' dose not name a type. There are more details:

```
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/opencv-3.2.0-dev/opencv2/core/eigen.hpp:63:22: error: ‘Eigen’ does not name a type
void eigen2cv( const Eigen::Matrix<_Tp, _rows, _cols, _options, _maxRows, _maxC
                  ^
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/opencv-3.2.0-dev/opencv2/core/eigen.hpp:63:35: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘<’ token
void eigen2cv( const Eigen::Matrix<_Tp, _rows, _cols, _options, _maxRows, _maxC
                               ^
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/opencv-3.2.0-dev/opencv2/core/eigen.hpp:63:35: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘<’ token
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/opencv-3.2.0-dev/opencv2/core/eigen.hpp:63:35: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/opencv-3.2.0-dev/opencv2/core/eigen.hpp:81:22: error: ‘Eigen’ does not name a type
void eigen2cv( const Eigen::Matrix<_Tp, _rows, _cols, _options, _maxRows, _maxC
                  ^
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/opencv-3.2.0-dev/opencv2/core/eigen.hpp:81:35: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘<’ token
void eigen2cv( const Eigen::Matrix<_Tp, _rows, _cols, _options, _maxRows, _maxC
                               ^
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/opencv-3.2.0-dev/opencv2/core/eigen.hpp:81:35: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘<’ token
```

I have already installed Eigen3,Opencv-2.4.13 and ROS-Kinetic with OpenCV-3.2.0. My CmakeLists looks like this:

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED) 

include_directories(
include
${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}
)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You kind of already found the solution: You need to include `Eigen/Core` before `opencv2/core/eigen.hpp`. I have no idea why opencv decided not to include that automatically.

Comment: Yes, that answer solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: It is solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876209/using-eigen-library-with-opencv-2-3-1